# Drawing a time line in latex

Tags: latex

I am drawing a time-line in latex. It looks like this, as of now I made it in excel. Wanted to check if someone has used latex for something like this.

[image]

Comment: What do you call a timeline here? I just see a table (which is something you can do in LaTeX) and using an arrow as character, which you can do too. Anyway you will probably have more help if you move your question to [tex.se] community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sketch

```latex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Time & 2 & 2.5 & 4.5 & 5\\
\hline
Truck & \cellcolor{blue!25} 1$\to$ 2 & \cellcolor{red!70!black} & \cellcolor{blue!25} 2$\to$ 1 & \cellcolor{red!70!black} \\
\hline
Car & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{black!10} 1$\to$ 4$\to$ 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{black!10} 2$\to$ 3$\to$ 1}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image: screenshot of output table]